# How can I sign a transaction using c or c++(arduino)

Tags: transactions, signature, raw-transaction

I want to create and sign transactions on arduino as offline.But I am not know this.Please help me.

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you have any experience in programming?

Comment: You basically need to compile the `accounts/keystore` directory into shared library using CGo, and then call library functions from C++.  I have already done it and I can do this as a commercial project, if you need it , let me know by adding your contact data on your profile.

Comment: @Nulik What is the library name?

Comment: you have to create it by compiling ethereum `geth` go-sources